# Need help with a sed script for specific word replacements in a text file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

I'm trying to automate a specific text replacement task for Romanian text using `sed` or any other suitable Unix tool. Here are my requirements:

1. Replace all instances of the letter `â` with `î` inside words.
2. Words that have in their composition the root "român" (like "Românească", "românește" etc.) should remain unchanged.
3. The word "sunt" should be replaced with "sînt".

For example:

Input:

```
până
împământenit
român
Românească
sunt
cugetând
```

Expected Output:

```
pînă
împămîntenit
român
Românească
sînt
cugetînd
```

I've tried several `sed` scripts, but none of them have been able to fulfill all requirements simultaneously. Can someone please guide me on this? I'd appreciate any help or advice!

Comment: Should `foosuntbar` be replaced with `foosîntbar` or not? Should `notaromân` be replaced with `notaromîn` or not? Should `românsunt` be replaced with `românsînt`  or not? Do you always only have 1 word per line? Please [edit] your question to state all of those requirements and any others currently unstated. Don't answer in a comment where it can't be formatted and could be missed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you describe it,

```
sed '/[rR]omân/!s/â/î/g;s/sunt/sînt/g'
```

will do the job:

- `s/â/î/g` does `s`ubstiture all (`g`lobal) occurences of `â` with `î`
- The "address" `/[rR]omân/` is inverted by the `!`, so the following command will not be applied for lines containing that pattern
- `s/sunt/sînt/g` finally replaces that word, also as part of componitions

Note: In your example, `ă` does also get replaced. If that is desired, you would need

```
sed '/[rR]omân/!s/[âă]/î/g;s/sunt/sînt/g'
```

Comment: Many thanks! Regarding your note: it was a typo of mine! Again, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You might also want to write this script to a file, which you can invoke with `sed -f`. That way you can put each command on a separate line and omit semicolons, which might be easier to read. You can also put spaces around each part of the command if you prefer, e.g. `/[rR]omân/ ! s/[âă]/î/g ; s/sunt/sînt/g`

Comment: @shadowtalker True except for the space after `!`: According to [POSIX](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/sed/), *»It is unspecified whether <blank> characters can follow a '!'  character, and conforming applications shall not follow a '!'  character with <blank> characters.«*

Comment: Good to know! Thanks for the link, I always appreciate knowing what POSIX says.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne 'S:g/â/î/ andthen                                  \
             S:samecase:g/ (<[rR]>om) (î) (n) /$0â$2/ andthen  \
             S:g/sunt/sînt/ andthen .put;'    file
```

Sample Input:

```
până
împământenit
român
Românească
sunt
cugetând
```

Sample Output:

```
pînă
împămîntenit
român
Românească
sînt
cugetînd
```

Raku has `-ne` non-autoprinting commandline flags. When substituting you can use Raku's "big-S" `S///` notation to  ***return the resultant string***.

Above the connector `andthen` will reload the topic variable (`$_`), so each successive `S///` works on the previously-modified text. The final clause `andthen .put` reloads the topic variable (`$_`) and prints out the final text ( `.put` is an abbreviation for `$_.put` ).

Note, you might prefer to use Unicode names as it saves on cutting/pasting special characters. Thus in Raku the first vowel substitution can actually be written as follows:

```
S:g/\c[LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX]/\c[LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH CIRCUMFLEX]/
```

https://raku.org